# You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: apex, batch, future

i have written a future method here is source code

```
@future(callout=true)
   public static void futureDownloadAttachment(Set<ID> documentsID){
    List<SpringCM_Attachment__c> logs = [Select Id,Object_ID__c,SpringCM_Document_Id__c,Attachment_Id__c From SpringCM_Attachment__c Where Id IN :documentsId];
    System.debug('logs are'+logs);
    for(Integer i=0;i<logs.size(); i++)
     if(logs[i].Attachment_Id__c == null)
    { logs[i] = downloadAttachment(logs[i]);
    update logs[i] ;
    }
   }

   public static SpringCM_Attachment__c downloadAttachment(SpringCM_Attachment__c log){
    System.debug('coming here');
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndPoint(SpringCM_Uploader_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults().Heroku_service__c+'/downloadDocument?documentId='+log.SpringCM_Document_Id__c);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    System.debug('response body is'+res.getBody());   
    AttachmentInfo attachInfo;
   Attachment a;
    if(res.getStatusCode() ==200)
    {   attachInfo = (AttachmentInfo) System.JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),AttachmentInfo.class);
        log.Status__c = AttachInfo.Status;
        log.Upload_details__c = AttachInfo.detail;

    if(attachInfo.DocumentDownloadResult != null)
 {   a = new Attachment(); 
    a.Body = Blob.valueOf(attachInfo.DocumentDownloadResult);
    a.Name= attachInfo.documentName;
    a.ParentId = log.Object_Id__c;   
     furtherProcess = false;
    insert a;
 }
 }  

    if(res.getStatusCode() != 200)
    {   log.Status__c = 'Error - Heroku';
        log.Upload_details__c = res.getBody().substring(0,2490);
    }       
    log.Object_type__c = String.valueOf(((ID)log.Object_ID__c).getSObjectType());
        if(a != null)
        log.Attachment_ID__c = a.Id;
        return log;
    }
```

i am getting error You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out.how to resolve this issue.Please help

Answer (score 10):

This is a very common issue that one encounters

> **The issue happens you are doing a DML before you do a Callout .To replicate this issue one can try things like**

```
Account acc=new Account();
acc.Name='Test exception';
insert acc;//insert a dummy account

Http h = new Http();//DO a HTTP callout 
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
 req.setEndPoint(SpringCM_Uploader_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults().Heroku_service__c+'/downloadDocument?documentId='+log.SpringCM_Document_Id__c);
req.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug('response body is'+res.getBody());
```

> **Resolution when using button to invoke**
>
> This workaround splits the transaction into two separate Ajax processes. The first inserts the record and the second performs the callout and is able to update the newly inserted record.****

```
   <!-- TestWsCallout.page -->
   <apex:page controller="TestWsCallout" tabstyle="Account">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!InsertRecord}" name="InsertRecord_JS" Rerender="statuses" status="Status1" oncomplete="CallWebService_JS();"/>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!CallWebService}" name="CallWebService_JS" status="Status2" reRender="statuses, msg"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="statuses">
        <apex:actionStatus id="Status1" startText="...Inserting Record Into DB..." />
        <apex:actionStatus id="Status2" startText="...Calling Web Service..." />
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="msg">
        <apex:pageMessages />
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <div><input name="DoAction" class="btn" type="button" value="Do Action" onclick="InsertRecord_JS();return false;"/></div>
</apex:form>
```

```
// TestWsCallout.cls
  public class TestWsCallout{
   Account myAccount;

  public PageReference InsertRecord() {
    myAccount = new Account(name = 'Test Account');
    insert myAccount;
    // Calling a Web Service here would throw an exception
    return null;
  }

public PageReference CallWebService() {

    // Execute a call to a Web Service
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('http://MyWebService12345678790.com?id=' + myAccount.Id);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = new Http().send(req);

    // Simulate an update
    myAccount.Name = 'Test Account 2';
    update myAccount;        
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'WebService Called on New Account: ' + myAccount.Name));
    return null;
   }
 }
```

> **Resolution when using In Trigger**
>
> If your transaction allows you to split your calls,that will be best route.One call will be for DML and  other for Callout(Mutiple future callouts)
>
> > **Another way will be first do a Callout and then do a DML and even this would also avoid this exception .

Comment: I am facing the same error. What happen if the callout is made from dml only?[insert acc -> trigger(after insert)-> call @future method -> call callout] In sandbox while testing i am not getting any error, but whiile deploying to production i got this error. please help: see my post here : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183649/on-post-request-system-calloutexception-please-commit-or-rollback-before-cal

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you perform your DML before the callout
[see this salesforce article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003701)

Comment: You just say the opposite to the link you provided. There it says: Web Service Callout may not occur after a DML statement.