# On post request- System.CalloutException: . Please commit or rollback before calling out"?

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api, code-coverage, failing-tests

```
public with sharing class CalloutHandler {

@future (callout=true)
public static void createAccount(String id)
{
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    String endPoint='https://portal/webapi/createorg.jsp';
    req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    String accountinfo = getAccountDetail(id);
    System.debug(accountinfo);
    req.setBody(accountinfo);
    try{
        HttpResponse response = http.send(req);  
        if(response.getStatusCode() !=200)
        {
         System.debug('Status code return was not expected: '+ response.getStatusCode() +' '+response.getStatus());
        }
        else{
          String constitid =response.getBody();
          System.debug(constitid);  
          //some stuff
        } 
  }catch(System.CalloutException e){
      System.debug(e); 
 }
```

}

Comment: Take a look at these [search results](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=Please+commit+or+rollback+before+calling+out) from this site. You must do the callout before you do any DML in the transaction.

Comment: I have a web service call out that is working fine.  The web service callout is triggered in an After Trigger, which call @future method in the above class , which then make the callout.  In test class , In my testmethod for this, I start by setting up some test data(list of accouunt: accts)  and inside Test.startTest and Test.stopTest , i mock the response first and then did dml operation : "insert accts".

Comment: I knew that inserts performed in test methods are not committed, thats why i am getting this error. but according to requirment, the callout is made from DML.( insert acc-> trigger -> call @future method -> call callout.

Comment: Add this extra detail to your question: are you saying you only get the error in your test case? If so include that in the question.

Comment: While tesing in sandbox , i am not getting any error(Test method pass), but while deploying into production, its fail and gave me this error

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Ah0GIAS I follow this link(mentioned the same issue), i have to use Test.isRunningTest method in my CalloutHandler class, but dont know how to use it.

Comment: You use it to not make the callout all all when `Test.isRunningTest()` returns true which means you are in a test case. If you are doing a lot of callouts the preferred technique in tests is described in e.g. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html.

Comment: yes i am using MultiRequestMock to get fake response.

Comment: @Keith C  Finally, i found the main reason behind this error in production. Sandbox and Production org both have different data and configuration. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hHVZAA2.  System.CalloutException: . Please commit or rollback before calling out" error is occur if some workflow rule is active on object(on which test methods are written) that sends an email alert will cause test methods using mock implementations to fail due to uncommitted work pending. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XHBAA2,